# woocommerce - extra field on product selection

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to add a gift card(actual card and electronic) with the following fields.

1. Delivery(Standard, Fast, Visual)
2. Customer email address

if someone selects standard/fast, the customer email address field hides. When selecting Visual, the customer email address field and require to enter email address. What's the way to do this? Cheers.